# Upgrade problem from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

Today i tried to upgrade my Linux Ubuntu many times, i encountered a problem showed in the attached picture, the messages showed (Fail to fetch.... esm package, unauthorized 401 error plus an I.P address written lastly), any way to resolve this problem?
[the problem showed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3vF1.jpg)

Comment: The image shows that you are running an ESM version. Can you confirm that you are running 20.04? It is not an ESM release.

Comment: From setting >> about the version is showed in OS name it showed 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: Did you make any changes to your repository settings like enable ESM which does not exist  yet for 20.04 and wont until at leadt 2025?  Were you trying to get *old* python which will break your system if you try to install it?

Comment: I use old python, but i don't know how ESM  are installed to my system and cause abort system upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Now i resolved the upgrade simply by removing all ESM repo from the "Software & Updates" → other software , tick all ESM repo → remove all and refresh.

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer. I don't even know what ESM *is*, yet the repos were somehow enabled on my 20.04 install as well. Unamused that Ubuntu once again inserts stuff into my repo lists without informing the user in some way.